# .env variables showing as undefined in create-react-app UI

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv

I am trying to set up build-specific environment variables for use in our front-end (**not** NodeJS) ReactJS application initialised using **create-react-app**.

I have created three files in my project root: *.env, .env.development, .env.production*

For testing purposes I have put these variables in each .env file:

```
REACT_APP_TEST_KEY=1
TEST_KEY=1
```

And in my app.js file in the render function, I have added these debug lines:

```
  console.log(`.env test key: ${process.env.REACT_APP_TEST_KEY}`);
  console.log(`.env test key: ${process.env.TEST_KEY}`);
```

After saving all, I then run **npm start** at the command line.

The result is as follows:

```
.env test key: undefined
.env test key: undefined
```

As you can see I have tried to hedge on the subject of whether one should or should not be using the prepend **REACT_APP**.

I have spent hours reviewing the various blog posts on this subject, as well as the two most popular questions asked on SO on this subject, and I still don't feel I have an answer, especially as some of the responses confuse whether it'll work only in node and not in the browser, and that the create-react-app 
[documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) some same has not been updated.

That documentation, btw, clearly implies that this should run out of the box with no additional edits to the package.json file. I've included it below, in any case:

```
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "msal": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-stl-obj-viewer": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
  }
```

Comment: env variable must start with REACT_APP_YOURENVNAME

Comment: Is your problem solved??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and suggestions.

Well it turned out to be something silly. I was putting my .env files in **/src** and not the project root - something easily done when you have over 50 files in a project and the indentations on the folder viewer in Visual Studio Code are so small.

Once I moved the files to the top-level folder (above **/src**), everything work.

(Insert facepalm .gif here)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be maybe missing some point following the docs, I have tried replicating the steps to see env variables, on both my local repo and a codesandbox repo.

Both of them seem to be logging the expected env variable.

See [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-burnell-dft8y?file=/src/App.js) repo for more details. Please share the repo details if you have the code hosted somewhere else.